# C# : Deserialize xml with an unknow number of attributes

Tags: c#, xml, class, deserialization

I would like to deserialize xml files with the following pattern :
[image]

I would like to put the data into a class call `Parameter`. However, as you can see, I don't knwo by advance how many <Device> I get between <Parameters> ... </Parameters> and the deserialization is not possible with such a DeserializeObjectXMLFile method.

```
public static Parameters DeserializeObjectXMLFile(String fileToRead)
        {
            try
            {
                Parameters parameters = null;
                XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Parameters));
                
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileToRead))
                {
                    parameters = xs.Deserialize(sr) as Parameters;
                }
                
                return parameters;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Error(ex);

                throw ex;

            }
        }
```

I imagined having a property `List<Device> Devices {get; set}` in my `Parameters` class but deserialization won't work and I don't know how I can do it.

Could you help me in finding a solution ?

Best regards.

Rémi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `XmlDocument` object in the `System.Xml` namespace to parse the XML instead of serializing it.

Here is an example:

```
var xDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load(pathToXml);

foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode node in xDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes) 
{
     var attrName = node.Attributes[0].Name;
     var attrValue = node.Attributes[0].Value;
     Device dev = new Device(attrName, attrValue);
     deviceList.Add(dev);
}
```

While parsing you can then create a new instance of `Parameters` and add it to a List object.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser Nino.

However, It doesn't really help me... Indeed, the file is auto generated, and if a new attribute is added in the Device node (Version fors exemple) and if Version and Reference are place in different order... It won't work... Moreover, I have a TestManager node that must be treated completely differntly.

Comment: OK, I mature the solution, I may adapt it... I'll update you !

Comment: @Remi Serialization is generally used to output something, but you are trying to use serialization for input. When the structure is unknown I would recommend creating a generic parser. When you parse the XML node by node you can create a map or index of attributes and elements. The position of an attribute is irrelevant, all you need to check is if the attribute `Version` already exists in your map/index and add it if necessary.

Comment: Thank you. Finally I go for it !